# How can I create session in my chrome extension using javascript?

Tags: javascript, session, google-chrome-extension

I am new in developing chrome extensions and need little bit guidance for it.

I have to maintain session inside my extension for login, after login have to preserve key & use it for further processing. its good if someone share useful links for basic understanding of session creation using javascript.

Comment: So you're just asking how to store data? http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean session storage [look here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) 
`sessionStorage` object will be deleted when the browser window is closed - but will survive any page refreshes. It is an ideal place for storing session ids and alike.

Comment: If your answer is just a link, it may be a comment. Or edit and explain more.